# Post-commit hook not executing

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

### The problem

I am using `SVN` for revision control.
I would like to use the `post-commit` hook in order to get a script executed, but for some reason it does not trigger.

Any ideas what might be the reason?

---

### Additional information

- My server is a `Windows Server 2012`
- I am using `VisualSVN Server 2.7.4`
- I have changed the `post-commit.tmpl` file in the `hooks` folder to `post-commit.bat`
- I am using the `http` protocol in order to access the server.

### What have I tried so far

- I have modified the `post-commit.bat` file to create an empty file in `c:\` for validating that the hook was executed (it did not...)
- The script works perfectly from command line.
- I changed the protocol to `file://` (and shared the folder of the repo) - no good...

---

### Solution

As @bahrep and @Dialecticus pointed out, it was not smart on my side to create the test file on root c:. after creating it within a subfolder with full permissions for everybody, the file was created, e.g. the hook was triggered after all.

Comment: To me it looks like a permission issue on the hook folder . **Subversion executes hooks as the same user who owns the process that is accessing the Subversion repository** Please check if this is in place?

Comment: It has `Modify` permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the empty file in C:\Temp folder. Writing to the root of C: requires special privileges that you may have, but the account under which SVN server is running may not have.

Also, try another test, just in case. Make `pre-revprop-change.bat` hook with a sole line of code "exit 0", and try to change some revision's log message, or even author, and see if that works.

Comment: Right on the spot. after setting the file to be created in the subfolder (with full permissions for everyone), The file was created, meaning the hook was triggered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. As @JyotsnaSaroha already mentioned, Subversion hooks are executed under the account which runs VisualSVN Server's service. The service runs under `Network Service` account, by default, so the account must have access permissions to the directory / file you need it to operate with.
2. You don't need to edit / rename `*.tmpl` hook files, just use VisualSVN Server's built-in hook editor in VisualSVN Server Manager console.
3. I strongly discourage to use post-commit hook to create anything in `C:\`. Use some other directory, such as `C:\myhookdirectory`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `1`:Forgot to mention that, I did check it and the service had `Modify` permissions. `2`: When looking via VisualSvn, it shows the modification, so I guess it is the same... `3` It is just for debugging...

Comment: Update: After testing again, with a sub folder in c:\ it seems you had a point their. The file is being created, so the hook is being triggered. Wish I could mark both answers as `accepted`, but I can't so i'll go with the first one...